# Coq Qed tactics get hang

Tags: coq

I proved a lemma (Proof completed), but when I am saving it using Qed, the system gets busy. 
In the same file, there are other similar lemmas where Qed performs normal, except this one. 
Can any body teach me its solution?

Thanks,

Wilayat

Comment: Could you provide the error-producing code?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without knowing in which particular example you are working on. Whenever you type `Qed` in Coq, the kernel will analyze the proof that your tactics produced and make sure that it actually is valid; the tactic engine itself actually doesn't perform many checks. Thus, even though your problematic proof was just slightly different from the other ones, something probably caused it to produce a very big proof term, which makes the kernel take a long time.

Comment: @Ptival Here is the error-producing code. I now fixed it. I still dont understand the problem. If the two lines are un-commented, then after tactic `destruct p; intuition.`, the proof completes, but `Qed` gets hanged. `Lemma vis_handle
 : forall l wr pr u b wrq oel, 
  top_label <?= l = true ->
  (wrq, oel) = handle_w wr pr u b ->
  List.filter (vis_oe_b l) oel == oel.
Proof with o.
intros. (*
unfold handle_w in H0.
unfold open_w in H0. *)
inversion H0. simpl in *. rewrite -> H; simpl.  
unfold url_label; simpl. 
destruct l in *; destruct u;  simpl in *...
destruct p; intuition. Qed. `